# Proof of the Saint-Venant compatibility equations

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics

In the Mechanics of deformable solids, and specifically in the Theory of Elasticity, the following mathematical relation is known:

$$ 2 \cdot \frac{\partial^2 \epsilon_{12}}{\partial x_{1} \partial x_{2}} = \frac{\partial^2 \epsilon_{11}}{\partial x_{2}^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \epsilon_{22}}{\partial x_{1}^2}$$

which makes it possible to establish a connection between tangential or shear deformation and normal deformations.

I have tried to locate in several books on Elasticity Theory a mathematical demonstration of the above equation, but the search has not been satisfactory, since I have not found anything in any book. On the other hand, I have tried to prove it without going to books, but to be honest I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have a strain field and you want to obtain the displacements. You could directly integrate the strain-displacement relations

$$\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} = 2\epsilon_{ij}\, .$$

This is a system of six equations and three unknowns. Theoretically, you only need three equations to determine the displacement fields. You can't pick the strain components $\epsilon_{ij}$ arbitrarily.

To have a unique solution for $u_i$ you need some constraints on the strains. If you differentiate the above equation an interchange some of the indices you obtain

$$\frac{\partial^2 \epsilon_{ij}}{\partial x_k \partial x_l}
+ \frac{\partial^2 \epsilon_{kl}}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}
- \frac{\partial^2 \epsilon_{il}}{\partial x_j \partial x_l}
- \frac{\partial^2 \epsilon_{jl}}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}  = 0\, .$$

From there you have 81 equations, but some of them are trivial. From those only six are nontrivial, and one of those is the one you present.